# Issue with Preconfiguring "base-passwd"

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm unable to upgrade Ubuntu packages. Please help us on this.

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

I'm getting a bellow error message.

```
634 upgraded, 74 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
157 standard LTS security updates
Need to get 12.5 MB/951 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,035 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 
2.0.20+dfsg-2ubuntu1.22.04.1 [582 kB]
Fetched 12.5 MB in 16s (773 kB/s)
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up base-passwd (3.5.52build1) ...
Changing home-directory of irc from /var/run/ircd to /run/ircd
1 changes have been made, rewriting files
Writing passwd-file to /etc/passwd
Error making backupfile /etc/passwd.org: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package base-passwd (--configure):
 installed base-passwd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
Errors were encountered while processing:
 base-passwd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please add the output of `findmnt -T /etc`

Comment: Here is the output### findmnt -T /etc
TARGET SOURCE                      FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ext3   rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro

Comment: OK thanks so that rules out one possible issue however we still don't know exactly what command produced the error shown - your title says it's an issue with "Preconfiguring" but it's unclear whether that was a direct `dpkg` command or part of an `apt` update or install. The more context you can give us the better the chance of resolution.

Comment: I'm trying to patch Ubuntu Linux with "apt upgrade -y" command but it gives us above mentioned error without installing any package.

Comment: Let me know if any further details required.

Comment: OK so can we assume you ran `apt upgrade -y` as root? I'm trying to understand why `Error making backupfile /etc/passwd.org: Permission denied` in that case. If you *did* run it as root, then you will need to investigate what file and directory permissions are preventing creation or writing of the backupfile.